# WPF - cannot parse TextBlock element from string

Tags: wpf, uielement, xamlreader

I'm new in WPF

I need to get string param, create an UIElement and attach it to the view.
Parsing the element from the string is failed, I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
public void addElementToView(string str)
{
      object obj = XamlReader.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(str)));
      UIElement elem = (UIElement)obj;
      SpecialContent.Children.Add(elem);
}
```

call `addElementToView("<TextBox Text=\"hello\"/>")` fails with the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type 'TextBlock'.' Line number '1' and line position '2'.

It failes in this row:

```
object obj = XamlReader.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(str)));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the necessery namespace in xml. like following,

```
addElementToView("<TextBox Text=\"hello\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>");
```